# How to create sidebar in GTK+3 (Python)?

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm fairly new to GTK+3 (I use PyGObject) and I need to create a sidebar that has a structure like this:

```
Header 1
    Subheader 1
    Subheader 2

Header 2
    Subheader 3
    Subheader 4
```

What examples can I learn from? Could you show me a minimal working example of how to use `Gtk.Treeview` and `Gtk.TreeModel` (not using `Gtk.Builder()`)?

Besides using a xml file and `Gtk.Builder()` to describe the layout seems superior to creating the structure in the python file, but there seems to be much less documentation for doing so.

**My current UI description:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
    <object class="GtkWindow" id="main-window">
        <property name="title">ApplicationName</property>
        <signal name="delete-event" handler="onDeleteWindow"/>
        <child>
            <object class="GtkBox" id="container">
                <property name="orientation">horizontal</property>
                <child>
                    <object class="GtkTreeView" id="sidebar">
                    </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                    <object class="GtkBox" id="right-container">
                        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
                        <child>
                            <object class="GtkButtonBox" id="top-buttonbox">
                                <child>
                                    <object class="GtkButton" id="add-button">
                                        <property name="label">Add</property>
                                    </object>
                                </child>
                                <child>
                                    <object class="GtkButton" id="delete-button">
                                        <property name="label">Delete</property>
                                    </object>
                                </child>
                            </object>
                        </child>
                    </object>
                </child>
            </object>
        </child>
    </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at the `GtkTreeView` and the associated tree-like data model `GtkTreeStore`. The [Python GTK+ 3.0 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html) is a good introduction.

Comment: I have already looked at these, but I can't figure out how to use them  in an xml file to create such a menu. Should I create one column? How do I insert the "data"? I have updated the question to include my xml file.

Comment: I have also tried Glade, but I can't make it produce the sidebar.

Comment: Use a `GtkPaned` as your main container, one pane for your main UI and the other for a `GtkTreeView`, I supose that's the look you want to achieve.

Comment: @asermax It's getting `GtkTreeView` to work that's the problem.

Comment: You create a new `GtkTreeStore` with whatever data columns you like. Then you insert your actual data into that model one by one, specifying the parent node to model the parent-child-relationship. The tutorial is not an API reference, so you are better off with the [C reference](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkTreeStore.html#gtk-tree-store-insert).

Comment: @dexterity Glade actually offers to create a new store when you add a treeview to the UI, it's pretty straight forward

Comment: @asermax Regarding `GtkPaned`, how do I create a layout with 3 panes?

Comment: @dexterity there isn't a widget for that, that I know of. You'll probably have to nest `GtkPaned`s or make a custom widget.